# Subscription managment for ios applications

Tags: ios, in-app

I try to publish a new app on the ios store. But they don't want to publish it cause i use an external payment system to manage users subscriptions.

My question is :
Can I have a payment system on my website so that users can pay for their subscription and activate their account. And do not use any payment method in my application and then i do not add the inapp purchase?

Comment: You can, but your app cannot link directly to your website (i.e. you cannot provide a "register" or "subscribe" button in your app that opens your website).  All you can do is present a username/password screen where users can enter their previously registered details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I will apply the solution of the login screen and submit my application to the apple store.

can you post your reply as an answer ?